# Hedges estimator and random effects in meta-analisis with {metafor}

Tags: r

I am using log response ratio (“ROM”) as effect size with Hedges Estimator (“HE”) in metafor:

```
rma(es, var, mods=~ Myc * N , method="HE", data=dat, weights=weightsTime)
```

Now I want to include a random effect, however `rma.mv` only allows `method=REML`or `method=ML`. This would be my desired model:

```
rma.mv(es, var, mods=~ Myc * N, random = list(~ Myc|SPS.in.SITE, ~N|SPS.in.SITE), method="HE", data=dat, W=weightsTime)
```

But `method="HE"`is not a valid option.
How can I include a random effect using Hedges Estimator?
Thanks

Comment: There is a typo in your post (in your code ?). It should be `method="HE"`, not `method=“HE"`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. the typo was in the post only. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `rma.mv()` only does ML/REML estimation. Other estimators, such as HE, DL, and so on (available with `rma.uni()`) have not been generalized to all the complex data structures that the `rma.mv()` function handles. The nice thing about (restricted) maximum likelihood estimation is that it is a general framework that works as long as you can write down the likelihood function. Plus, ML/REML estimators have nice and well-studied statistical properties.